# Using directive scope to update Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts

I have two charts with different `ids` (`#chart1` and `#chart2`). I've created a button, so I can change a chart's type (e.g. from column to line):

```
<button ng-click="updateChart(name, 'line')">Line</button>
```

This button calls the `updateChart` function:

```
$scope.updateChart = function(id, type) {
  var chart = $('#' + id).highcharts();
  chart.series[0].update({
    type: type
  });
};
```

As I need to call the button for every chart, I've created a directive passing a `name` value to the scope:

```
.directive('changeChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        name: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: "change-chart.html"
  };
})
```

In my HTML I call the directive passing the chart id: `<change-chart name="chart1"></change-chart>`

However, the button isn't working. It only works if I remove the directive scope and set the `id` manually. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5wmLldmXpoq9wiMACbNS?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when you define a scope object in your directive, it creates an isolate scope for that directive. That means, the scope within your directive cannot access the scope properties defined outside. You have your controller defined on the outer scope where you attach the function `updateChart`. So, your isolate scope directive is not aware of this method.

To fix this, you can define a controller on your directive itself. And in that controller, define the method `updateChart`

```
.directive('changeChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        name: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.updateChart = function(id, type) {
            var chart = $('#' + id).highcharts();
            chart.series[0].update({
                type: type
            });
        };
    },
    templateUrl: "change-chart.html"
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This solved the issue. :)